# PageRequest constructors have been deprecated

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-commons

I'm working the Spring Data Commons v2+ snapshot, and I see that the constructors for a `PageRequest` have been deprecated.  This appears to have occurred between [M1](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/2.0.0.M1/api/org/springframework/data/domain/PageRequest.html#constructor.summary) & [M2](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/2.0.0.M2/api/org/springframework/data/domain/PageRequest.html#constructor.summary).  Unfortunately, this is the only [real] implementation of the `Pageable` interface.  I'm wondering where the effort is heading, and what a better alternative would be for current development.

Comment: It is appears also at the [M3]http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/2.0.0.M3/api/org/springframework/data/domain/PageRequest.html#constructor.summary

Answer (score 204, accepted):

It's just the constructors which have been deprecated. Instead of

```
new PageRequest(firstResult, maxResults, new Sort(...))
```

you can now use

```
PageRequest.of(firstResult, maxResults, Sort.by(...))
```

and that's it.

Comment: Spring Boot 2.0.0.RC1, For example: `Page<Ccy> currencyList = ccyRepository.findAll(PageRequest.of(evalPage, evalPageSize));`

Comment: Since Spring v2.0 use the static PageRequest::of method instead of constructing a new PageRequest instance. See more https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/PageRequest.html

Comment: I wonder why the Spring Data reference is still using the deprecated constructors in the examples, given that it has been more than a year they are deprecated.

Comment: This will also work if you previously the constructor without passing in a Sort instance.

Comment: Yep, and I wonder why the javadoc does not tell anything about the deprecation reason and does not mention the new factory methods.

Answer (score 13):

We can use `PageRequest.of(offset, limit)` instead of `new PageRequest(offset, limit)`.
In this case we don't need to use deprecated constructor.

Answer (score 11):

You can use the following solution to solve your problem:

```
Page<User> users=userService.findByUserType(id,PageRequest.of(1, 3));
```

Comment: Please provide an explaination of why this solves the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Since **Spring v2.0**:
`PageRequest.of()` is a static method , you don't need to construct a `new PageRequest()` instance.

use this  **static** methode  for Creating a new unsorted `PageRequest` :

```
PageRequest.of(int page, int size)
```