# Spring boot 2.0.0+ pagination, maven and hibernate

Tags: spring-boot, pagination

I am making a springboot pagination  however :

repo.findAll (PageRequest.of (page, size) );

Doesn't seem to work.

Does anybody know the new way to paginate in spring boot 2+ after PageRequest(...) is deprecated?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please have a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44848653/pagerequest-constructors-have-been-deprecated

Answer (score 0):

You need a `Pageable` object. **Sample snippet**:

```
@Repository
public interface MyRepo extends JpaRepository<MyDto, Long> {

  Page<MyEntity> findAll(Pageable page); 

}
```

`If you get the Pageable object from the controller, just pass it on or else if you want to manually construct, you can do like follows:

```
@Test
public void testPagination(){
 assertNotNull(myRepo.findAll(PageRequest.of(0, 20)));
}
```

This works for me! Make sure you return `Page<MyEntity>` instead of List?

Answer (score 0):

My mistake : repo.findAll (PageRequest.of (page, size) );
... is a working methodology. Thanks for your tme @karthik R