# How to fetch 500 rows at time until all items from table is fetched?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, java-8, spring-data-jpa

I have a table with over 10 000 rows. I am using Spring with JPA and i want to make a "batch" job where i can fetch 500 rows at time until there is no more to get from the table? I have a repository class which extends `JpaRepository<SchoolAdmin, Long>`.
I am new to Spring so i would appreciate if anyone can help me?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try something like this:

```
public interface SchoolAdminRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository< SchoolAdmin, Long> {
    List<SchoolAdmin> findAll(Pageable pageable);
}
```

Then call method providing a `Pageable` object:

```
List<SchoolAdmin> page = repository.findAll(PageRequest.of(pageNumber, 500));
```

Comment: But how do i know where to start for the next 500 rows? And how do i know how amny there are left? i Want to fetch 500 at time until all are fetched

Comment: The `pageNumber` will tell you where to start next (depending on page size).

Comment: But do i need to extend `PaginationAndSortingRepository` ?

Comment: It wont give me the method `.of` ? Does it depend on my spring version?

Comment: Perhaps you're using an old version. Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44848653/pagerequest-constructors-have-been-deprecated

Comment: Or you can replace the static `PageRequest::of` with constructor `new PageRequest(pageNumber, 500)`