# Delete on DATE TIME in Spring Boot JPA

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a very slow code here. All it does is that it colleting all rows with a specific entity column.

```
List<Data> slectedData = dataService.findByJobNameOrderByDateTime(selectJob.getValue().getName());
List<Data> deleteThese = slectedData.subList(firstIndex - 1, lastIndex);
    for (List<Data> deleteTheseLists : Lists.partition(deleteThese, 2000)) {
        dataService.deleteInBatch(deleteTheseLists);
}
```

Then I create a `sub list` and I want to delete that sublist.
But the sublist can be very large and then `dataService.deleteInBatch(deleteTheseLists);` takes alot of time.

The `entity` class `Data` looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Data {

    // ID
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    // Made by
    private String jobName;
    private String calibrationName;
    @Column(columnDefinition = "DATETIME(3)")
    private LocalDateTime dateTime;

    // Analog input
    private float sa0;
    private float sa1;
    private float sa1d;

}
```

And I want to delete on `dateTime`. Is that possible in Spring Boot JPA?
Because I can't delete on `id` because the `id` key is not correct indexed in the database because sometimes the database takes long time to insert data, and sometimes it goes fast. So it's a very unsecure way to delete `entities` in `JPA`.

Comment: The fastest option seems to be using `EntityManager` and  `Query`. https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/delete#Selective_Deletion

Comment: @RoarS. Is the answer below good enough?

Comment: I would tried both, and selected the one that meets the requirements

Comment: ... and please update us with your results, it would be very interesting to know the actual difference in performance. BR

Comment: @RoarS. Yes I can, but I need to do like this: `findByJobNameOrderByDateTime` with limit index e.g `between 200 and 300 rows`. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, the simplest solution I think will be to pass in an instance of `Pageable` as the last parameter. https://stackoverflow.com/a/40715106/14072498

Comment: @RoarS. But I don't know the page number. All I know is that how many `entities` there are. I want to `1.` sorting them on `Date time` and then select a range index. I could do like this, but it's so slow. https://github.com/DanielMartensson/OpenSourceLogger/blob/636f835770049427172543f629f7e71af793e497/src/main/java/se/danielmartensson/views/MySQLView.java#L141

Comment: Are you sure you need to sort on date? Is there a strong correlation between PK and date so you can use PK instead? E.g. if the date is create date?

Comment: @RoarS. Something like this `SELECT firstName, lastName, seatNumber FROM passengers ORDER BY seatNumber LIMIT 1 AND BEGINS AT 50`. Just making `AND BEGINS AT 50` by myself.

Comment: @RoarS. Yes, I need to sort in date time because I inserting them on date time.

Comment: @RoarS. Found that query example from this page https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-limit-query-results

Comment: @RoarS. Think I got it now `SELECT jobName FROM Data ORDER BY dateTime LIMIT min, max;` where `min` is my beginning and `max` is total rows counted from `min`.

Comment: @RoarS. Do you think this is correct `@Query("SELECT jobName FROM Data data ORDER BY data.dateTime LIMIT firstIndex, lastIndex")
 List<Data> findByJobNameOrderByDateTimeLimit(@Param("jobName") String jobName, @Param("firstIndex") long firstIndex, @Param("lastIndex") long lastIndex);` to getting `entities` that are ordered by `dateTime` and limited by a range?

Comment: You should probably write some tests about this to make sure things are working. Look up `@DataJpaTest`. There is a test in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65614205/14072498 BR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can delete by `dateTime` using [keywords](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation)

```
//equals
deleteByDateTimeEquals(LocalDateTime dateTime);

// lessthan
deleteByDateTimeLessThan(LocalDateTime dateTime);

// greaterthan
deleteByDateTimeGreaterThan(LocalDateTime dateTime);
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks! I will try that!

Comment: Annotate each of the method provided above with @Modifying

Comment: By the way! Can I have `deleteByDateTimeGreaterThanAndLessThan(DateTime great, DateTime less)` ?

Comment: @DanM I think you can have a `deleteByDateTimeBetween`. Otherwise you will have to do `deleteByDateTimeGreatherThanAndDateTimeLessthan`